# Limit definition of Sets.

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

**Proposition 1.32** $X_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$ *if and only if for any* $\epsilon>0$

$P( | X_{n}- X |<\epsilon, \; \forall n\geq m )\rightarrow1$ $as$ $ m\rightarrow\infty$

**Proof**. Suppose first that $X_{n} \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$. Fix $\epsilon>0$, and $m\geq1$ define the event

$A_m=\{| X_{n}-X |<\epsilon , \; \forall n\geq m\}$

**Because $A_m,m\geq1$, is an increasing sequence of events**, the continuity property of probabilities yields that

$$\lim_{m\to \infty}P(A_m)=P(\lim_{m\to \infty}A_m)=P(| X_{n}- X |<\epsilon \text { for all n sufficiently large})\geq P(\lim_{n \to \infty}X_n=X)=1$$

To go the other way, assume that for any $\epsilon>0$

$P(| X_{n}-X |<\epsilon, \; \forall n\geq m)\rightarrow1$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$ 
let $\epsilon_{i}, i\geq1$ be a decreasing sequence of postive numbers that converge to $0 $ and let

$A_{m,i}=\{| X_{n}-X |<\epsilon, \; \forall n\geq m\}$

**Because $A_{m,i}\subset A_{m+1,i}$ and**, by assumption, $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}P(A_{m,i})=1$ ......

1. The parts in bold that concern increasing and decreasing events confuse me thoroughly, I do not understand them :(
2. What does it actually mean to have $X_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.} X$?

Comment: You're not bad at LaTeX :) [at least compared to others I've seen on here].

Answer (score 1):

1.1. Perhaps, you might better understand $A_m$'s as follows:

$$A_1 = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_1(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, |X_2(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, |X_3(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, \dots \}$$

$$A_2 = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_2(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, |X_3(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, |X_4(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, \dots \}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$A_m = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_m(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, |X_{m+1}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, |X_{m+2}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon, \dots \}$$

$$\vdots$$

To be more elaborate, define:

$$B_1:= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_1(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon\}$$

$$B_2:= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_2(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon\}$$

$$B_3:= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_3(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon\}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$B_m:= \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_m(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon\}$$

$$\vdots$$

Then $$A_1 = B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3 \cap \cdots = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$$

$$A_2 = B_2 \cap B_3 \cap \cdots = \bigcap_{k=2}^{\infty} B_k$$

$$\vdots$$

$$A_m = B_m \cap B_{m+1} \cap \cdots = \bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty} B_k$$

$$\vdots$$

Hopefully, it is clear that $$A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_m \subseteq \cdots$$

---

1.2 I have a feeling you made a typo. Did you mean

$$A_{m,i} = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid |X_m(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon_i, |X_{m+1}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon_i, |X_{m+2}(\omega) - X(\omega)| < \epsilon_i, \dots \}$$

?

If so, then $$A_{m,i} \subseteq A_{m+1,i}$$ for the same reasons that $A_{m} \subseteq A_{m+1}$.

---

2. This is [almost sure convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence), the closest analogue to pointwise convergence from real analysis.

If we have random variables $X, X_1, X_2, \dots$ in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$, then $X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$ iff

$$P(\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X) := P(\omega \in \Omega \mid \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)) = 1$$

So if we collect all $(\omega_j)_{j \in J}$ s.t. $$\limsup X_n(\omega_j) = \liminf X_n(\omega_j) = X(\omega_j)$$, then we must have $$P(\bigcup_{j \in J} (\omega_j)) = 1$$